# Rordenar nombre de variables categóricas en eje "x" en gráfico beanplot

Tags: r

Hola quisiera saber si saben como modificar las variables en el eje "x" del siguiente gráfico para ordenarlas de la siguiente manera: Casa quemada, rio la playa y pasca

```
library(beanplot)

beanplot(Afe ~ Sectores, data = datos, col = "lightgray", border = "grey",
         overallline = "median", ylab = "cm^2 / g", xlab = "Sectores", 
         main = "Área Foliar Especifica")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución que suele funcionar en la mayoría de los casos, es transformar la variable del eje `x` en un `factor` con un orden predeterminado:

```
datos$Sectores <- factor(datos$Sectores, levels=c('Casa Quemada', 
                                                  'Río La Playa', 
                                                  'Pasca'))
```